# Is there a way to access the 2nd row of a 2d array using a pointer initialized to the first row?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory

Is there a way to access the 2nd row of a 2-dimensional array of char with a pointer variable set to the initial address of the array?
Example:

```
char a[2][10];
char *b=a[0];
```

Is there a way to access a[1] with the b pointer?

Comment: @MikeBorkland isn't that just creating new pointer variable? I was wondering if it was possible to just use the b variable? Or would I have to create a new pointer because the first row ends in a 'null'?

Comment: `a[i][j] == b[i * columnCount + j]` -> `a[i][j] == b[i * 10 + j]`

Comment: yes there is, but it is quite unsafe to do. you can exceed the bound of b to get a value from a forbidden area, and btw it's more of C than C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays are contiguous in memory, even nested arrays of arrays. In memory, and also drawn on paper, it would look something like this:

```
+---------+---------+-----+---------+---------+---------+-----+---------+
| a[0][0] | a[0][1] | ... | a[0][9] | a[1][0] | a[1][1] | ... | a[1][9] |
+---------+---------+-----+---------+---------+---------+-----+---------+
```

If you have a pointer to the first element you can then reach every other element by simple pointer arithmetic. For example, to read `a[0][2]` you simply use `b[2]`. To get `a[1][0]` you have `b[10]`. And so on.